# How to start a service only when a user log to Desktop Environment

Tags: linux

I trying to find a solution on starting a service or to execute a binary only when a user logs to his desktop environment. Basically, my binary is dependent on the Display environment of the user.

I tried with systemctl and PAM methods but unable to find a way. I tried with a script using cron, which would check the Display environment and start the binary. But i would like to use the service method rather than the cron method.

Comment: See [Launching Chromium on startup with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385964/1174) from the Unix&Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux environment is **systemd** based, you can create a systemd service unit for the user. See the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Writing_user_units).

As your application depends on the graphical environment for the user, I think it can be safer to use the **XDG** way: a [`.desktop`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) file under `~/.config/autostart` (for a single user) or under `/etc/xdg/autostart` for all users. See the [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).

Comment: Good answer, but it can be better if you put some examples into it, instead of just pointing to external resources (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135744).